# Why is transform.parent null in Awake() and Start()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm trying to get a reference to the GameObject that the script is attached to. Per docs `transform.parent.gameObject` is used for this but `transform.parent` is `null` in both `Awake()` and `Start()`. What do I need to do to get this working? This is probably a total noob question but Google didn't come up with a working answer so far.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        var obj = transform.parent;
        Debug.Log(obj);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        var obj = transform.parent;
        Debug.Log(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some code to get better response

Comment: The script doesn't have a parent in this case and all you need to do is to access it using "gameobject". (I assumed that the script is attached to a gameobject and not attached to a gameobject that is the child of another gameobject, the latter one being the one you want to find)

Comment: thanks! yes that was the case. See my answer, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Transform.parent](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html) tells you what the parent of your current transform is. I.E. if **GameObjectA** is a child of **GameObjectB**, a script that accesses transform.gameObject in **GameObjectB** will return **GameObjectA**

What you're looking for, in fact, is just **gameObject**. This implicitly returns the gameObject your script is attached to.

Create two GameObjects in your scene.
Call one **GameObjectA**, and the other **GameObjectB**.
Attach this script to **GameObjectB** and then drag **GameObjectB** to be under **GameObjectA** in the hierarchy

```
public class ExampleBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

    void Awake () {
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name);        //Prints "GameObjectB" to the console
        Debug.Log(transform.parent.name);  //Prints "GameObjectA" to the console
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind! I'm an idiot! It shouldn't be parent but:

```
var obj = transform or var obj = transform.gameObject
```

since this script is part of the game object which it should refer to, not any parent. I had the strange assumption that a script is a child of a game object.